# Socket.io, Node, Corodva, I don't recive message in client receptor

Tags: node.js, cordova, socket.io

I have a problem when I try send message from a client emisor with "emit" and I try catch the message with "on" in a client receptor.

I don't know what is the problem, my code is this:

Emisor Client:

```
socket.emit("callDriver", data);
```

Receptor Client:

```
socket.on("sendToDriver", function(data){

    console.log(data);

})
```

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        socket.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})
```

Thanks community

Comment: Regard the Emit cheatsheet and remember that most solutions like this usually involve Rooms or Redis! https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: Ok, but in theory if I send .emit('name', data) to server and I listen .on('name', functio...) I will should get data sended in the .emit in all clients that listen in this socket... this not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I resolved the problem, it's strange in the official documentation of Socket.io they say that when you send data in a .emit you should send this with "socket.emit()" (server side) but I try change socket for io and with this mode work it.

In conclusion:

```js
// I changed this:
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        socket.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})

// for this:
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        io.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you even testing with multiple receiving clients? Looks like you are just sending a multicast to all your clients with `io.emit`

Comment: Exactl, if I use io.emit working good, if I use socket.emit not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple rooms solution for you. The init() part is very low-tech/simple but you did not say how you intend to populate the socket server with the client userId/session-data when you connect to the server for the first time.

```
//Client
socket.on('connect',()=>{
 socket.on('init',()=>{
  socket.emit('init', 'userid')
 })
})
socket.on("sendToDriver", function(message){
  console.log(message);
})

sendMessage(message){
let data = {userId: "userId", message: message}
socket.emit("callDriver", data);
}

//Server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
//Triggered by each client separately.
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('init', (driverId)=>{
        //When your web socket starts for the first time, each user creates their own room with their main userId that is used in your mobile app.
        //Your setup is so basic, that the server('connection') -> server.emit('init') -> client.on('init') -> client.emit('init') flow is the most sane example for now.
        //However this init() setup is primitive -- you need an authentication flow and to pass up the userId/session data with a socket.io 'middleware' function or the 'socket.io-auth' library (recommended)
        socket.join(driverId)
    })
    socket.emit('init')
    //Data sent to callDriver will contain the userId of the desired receipient. Since this user is already waiting in that room for us, we join it, 
    //send the message, and then leave immediately. 
    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){
        socket.join(data.driverIdToCall)
        socket.to(data.driverIdToCall).emit('sendToDriver', data.message);
        socket.leave(data.driverIdToCall)
    })
})
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that the best practice for this is use rooms, but in theory if I send .emit('name', data) to server and I listen .on('name', functio...) I will should get data sended in the .emit in all clients that listen in this socket... this not working for me.